# project euler 22 using c#

Tags: c#

I am solving the same problem as here [Project Euler #22 Python, 2205 points missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493702/project-euler-22-python-2205-points-missing), but I am using C#. I can't find the mistake. Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> pole;

    static string SaveName(StreamReader reader)
    {
        int znak = reader.Read();
        string jmeno = "";

        while ((znak < 'A') || (znak > 'Z'))
        {
            znak = reader.Read();
        }

        while (znak != ',')
        {
            jmeno = jmeno + (char) znak;
            znak = reader.Read();
            if (znak == 34) break;
        }

        return jmeno;

    }

    static void SaveNamesIntoList()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"../../../names.txt");

        while (reader.Read() != ';')
        {
            pole.Add(SaveName(reader));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        pole = new List<string>();
        SaveNamesIntoList();
        pole.Sort();

        int sum = 0;
        int sum_word = 0;
        string name = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < pole.Count; i++)
        {
            name = pole[i];
            sum_word = 0;

            for (int u = 0; u < name.Length; u++)
            {
                sum_word += (name[u] - 'A' + 1);
            }

            sum += (sum_word * (i+1));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any answer:)

Comment: Where do you sort the list in alphabetical order?

Comment: The line with pole.Sort(); in the Main method (just after SaveNamesToList) somehow disapeared, but it is not the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ther reason why you have different result is than Czech language has specific letter 'CH' whitch is after 'H' so in alfabetical order without using right culture you can have sometring like this

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
czz
ddd
cha
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. You don't check if the reader reached the end of stream - you have to check if the `Read` returned -1. If it did - it's the end of the file. On top of that, you don't dispose the reader...

Then, as Cedric noted in the comments, you haven't really sorted the list, hence the result is wrong even after changing it to:

```
 using (var reader = new StreamReader("names.txt"))
 {
      while (reader.Read() != -1)
      {
          pole.Add(SaveName(reader));
      }
 }
```

What you need to do is add this line (which is a bit wasteful in general, but I'll get to that in a sec):

```
pole = pole.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); //<<----- this one
for (int i = 0; i < pole.Count; i++)
{
      name = pole[i];
      sum_word = 0;

      for (int u = 0; u < name.Length; u++)
      {
          sum_word += (name[u] - 'A' + 1);
      }

      sum2 += (sum_word*(i + 1));
 }
```

And the result is `871198282`, which should be correct - at least that's what the people are saying in the linked question.

Even then, might I suggest an easier way of solving that whole problem:

```
var scores = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1)
                       .Select((i, ch) => new { Character = (char) i, Weight = ch + 1 })
                       .ToDictionary(key => key.Character, val => val.Weight);

var sum = File.ReadAllText("names.txt")
                          .Split(',')
                          .Select(x => x.Trim('"'))
                          .OrderBy(x => x)
                          .Select((x, i) => (i + 1)*x.Select(y => scores[y]).Sum())
                          .Sum();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, as I replied to Cedric, the line with pole.Sort(); just after method SaveNameToList(); somehow dissapeared, so now consider, it is there. I added ";"(semicolon) in the end of file, so that I can test, whether I am already finished with reading a file. But also with  all these stuffs, I am having a result 872262771 instead of the right one ... :/

Comment: @arahusky Well, your code with the 'fixes' that I have introduced gives me the same result as my approach, which is 871198282...

Comment: OK, thanks :), then I have no idea, where could the problem be. Maybe in VS studio :D :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using Linq.

```
void Main()
{
    var file = @"C:\...location.of.file...\p022_names.txt";
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        NameScore(reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\"",string.Empty).Split(new[]{','})).Dump();  
    }
}

private long NameScore(string[] names)
{
    return names.OrderBy(o => o)
                .Select((l, i) => { return l.ToUpper().ToCharArray().Sum(s => (int)s - 64) * (i + 1);})
                .Sum(s => s);
}
```